# Composer file that is only additive

Tags: composer

We have a Drupal 8.x instance maintained by one team and would like to be able to have another team add modules to this without overriding/removing what is already there. Is this possible?

Comment: What's the problem with `composer require` ?

Comment: Tell the other team not to remove any modules from composer.json and use git version control so you can yell at them if they do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be using Composer and Git together:

- Use GIT and create feature branches and merge them into your production / develop branch
- Use $composer require drupal/module (keep the composer.json file in git repo)